# Count balls to put in triangle

Tags: geometry, algorithms, circles

Given balls of radius $R$ we need to find how many balls can be put into a triangular container with sides $a,b$ and $c$.

Example : Let $R=1$ and $a=3,b=4$ and $c=5$ then answer is $1$, as only one ball can be placed. Now how to solve it for given $R,a,b$ and $c$ ?

Comment: It depends on the height of the container.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Assume it all to be in 2d plane.and place circles instead of spheres

Comment: It is since long a known problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems#Packing_circles